# Allowing multiple authentication methods on same endpoint with security filter chains

Tags: spring, spring-security

I need my `/api/**` endpoints to be accessible using either a JWT token or a login/password.

I took inspiration from Spring documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity

But I may have misunderstood the example, and my API endpoints are only accessible using basic authent with this configuration :

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    static final int BCRYPT_PASSWORD_STRENGTH = 10;
    
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain apiSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, @Qualifier("apiUserDetailsService") UserDetailsService userDetailsService) throws Exception {

        http.antMatcher("/api/**")
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .exceptionHandling(configurer -> configurer.authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthenticationFallbackEntryPoint()))
                .sessionManagement(configurer -> configurer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, GrantedPortalRoleConverter grantedPortalRoleConverter) throws Exception {
        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedPortalRoleConverter);

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .exceptionHandling(configurer -> configurer.authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthenticationFallbackEntryPoint()))
                .sessionManagement(configurer -> configurer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .antMatchers(
                                "/swagger-ui/**",
                                "/swagger-ui.html",
                                "/swagger-resources/**",
                                "/v3/api-docs/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(configurer -> configurer.jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter));
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(BCRYPT_PASSWORD_STRENGTH);
    }   
}
```

How should I tweak this conf (still using `SecurityFilterChain`) to achieve my goal?

Comment: If you want to use both for the same endpoint, you don't need multiple chains, you need just one chain.

Comment: Ok, show me then pls. How to cumulate httpBasic with oauth2ResourceServer ? And have the custom "userDetailsService" only for httpBasic ?

Comment: What do you mean by *And have the custom "userDetailsService" only for httpBasic*? Do you use a second `userDetailsService`?

Comment: For httpBasic, I have this : .userDetailsService(userDetailsService) which uses a userDetailsService dedicated to httpBasic, for oauth2 I just need to use the default userDetailsService for OAuth2 using JWT token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is, the working config :

```java
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain basicAuthSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, @Qualifier("apiUserDetailsService") UserDetailsService userDetailsService) throws Exception {

        http.requestMatcher(new BasicAuthRequestMatcher())
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .exceptionHandling(configurer -> configurer.authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthenticationFallbackEntryPoint()))
                .sessionManagement(configurer -> configurer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, GrantedPortalRoleConverter grantedPortalRoleConverter) throws Exception {
        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedPortalRoleConverter);

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .exceptionHandling(configurer -> configurer.authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthenticationFallbackEntryPoint()))
                .sessionManagement(configurer -> configurer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .antMatchers(
                                "/swagger-ui/**",
                                "/swagger-ui.html",
                                "/swagger-resources/**",
                                "/v3/api-docs/**")                              
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(configurer -> configurer.jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter));
        return http.build();
    }
```

And the RequestMatcher :

```java
public class BasicAuthRequestMatcher implements RequestMatcher {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        return (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Basic");
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to extract common part of the config (e.g. `csrf()` and `cors()`) to separate `SecurityFilterChain` or it has to be repeated in every time?

Comment: Sure it can be tried to have only "http.csrf().disable()" in a SecurityChain with an early @Order but unless you have dozens of SecurityChain with the absolute  guarantee they will always have the same csrf conf, I don't think it's worth. This is conf duplication, it's not code duplication.